# Cannot find the entity manager for class

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am working on Symfony 6.1.12 after updating dependencies with the composer update command, I receive the above error when I do the symfony console make:entity command.
My composer.json file below
I tried to downgrade the doctrine/orm bundle as shown in this [example](https://github.com/symfony/maker-bundle/issues/1090#issuecomment-1103930333) but it don't work

```
{ 
  "require": {
     "php": ">=8.1",
     "ext-ctype": "*",
     "ext-iconv": "*",
     "doctrine/annotations": "^1.0",
     "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.7",
     "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.2",
     "doctrine/orm": "^2.14.1",
 },
 "conflict": {
     "symfony/symfony": "*"
 }
```

Comment: I remember running into this last year it it has been fixed for some time.  I just did a fresh 6.1 install (php 8.2) and make:entity works fine.  doctrine/orm should just be "^2.14" and doctrine-bundle should be "^2.8" (not 2.7).  Consider making a fresh 6.1 project, verify make:entity works and then comparing the full composer.json.

Comment: The above comment talked about the issue you linked but not the error in the title. Assuming make:entity does indeed work can you provide a few more details on what exactly triggers the error?  Are you trying to update an existing entity?  Usually the error will indicate which entity type is involved.

Comment: The error is triggered every time I use the make:entity command, even for a new entity, in my case, I was working with an Entity User. when I used the make:entity command the first time, the User.php and UserRepository.php were created when did the command the second time, I received this error: ` Cannot find the entity manager for class "App\Entity\User" `

Comment: Are you trying to use annotations?  In particular do you have a `type: annotation` property in your ORM configuration in doctrine.yaml?  For 6.x, when trying to use make:entity for a new entity it always first creates an empty entity using attributes.  It then tries to find the entity manager which will fail if the entity manager is configured to use annotations.  It is an interesting design to say the least.  [Another discussion on this topic](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/discussions/49329).

Comment: I didn't edit the doctrine.yaml file, I even started another project project using the --version=lts to have the long term support version. The make:entity command first work but when I wanted to use the make:entity command the second time, i receive the same error

Comment: Just to clarify you are not using annotations at all?  Your doctrine.yaml file does not have `type: annotation` in it?  I know I am being repetitive but you don't seem to be answering directly.  I just made a new 5.4 project and make:entity works fine on both new and existing attribute based entities.  In your question you specified that you were using 6.1 so I am not sure of your upgrade process.  In the past, 5.x doctrine.yaml files had the type: anotation property in them which is really the only reason I can think of for your error.

Comment: And please confirm you are using the 2.8 version (not 2.7) of the doctrine-bundle.  Seemingly small details can often be surprisingly important.

Comment: I am using 2.8 version

Comment: I found the problem, I was using the JWTRefreshTokenBundle which generated a Resfresh token entity which was using annotations instead of attributes. Thanks for the hints on annotations

Comment: Please share more details, and add all of them to your question by editing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

go to your `doctrine.yaml` file and comment out `type: annotation` then run your maker command again

Comment: After upgrading from annotations -> attributes this line is obligatory to be commented. Thx!

Comment: I am having this issue but there is not type: annotation in the doctrine's configuration of the project.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be you dont have the Repository annotation above your entity definition?

```
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ProductRepository::class)]
class Product
{
}
```

Comment: ` #[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ProductRepository::class)] `

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was declaring some custom validation constraint as annotation, you must convert it as Attribute.

To do so:
In your constraint, replace
/**

- @Annotation
  */
  By
  #[\Attribute]

And where you use it, use attribute instead
For lists as argument, use [] instead of {}, so
/**

- @UniqueNonNullField({"message", "videoUrl", "image"})
  */
  =>
  #[UniqueNonNullField(["message", "videoUrl", "image"])]

(This is specifically an answer for my issue, not the OP's one)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I tried to generate a new entity while I already had some entities created with annotations. I renamed the Entity directory and thought symfony would not use them but they where read in the renamed directory as well and lead to this error because of the annotations. Because I wanted to recreate my legacy entities to use migrations in the future, deleting the entire Entity directory helped me